# Show image in textview using Html.fromhtml();

Tags: android, html, android-image

I have a list adapter to show content frm my social network, i need to put inside the text the img tags, i've tried using Html.fromhtml and it's formatting the text but instead of shows the img it shows a gray square.

How can i achieve that? I'v read about ImageGetter but i still don't have it very clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can draw an `Image` in `TextView` using the `Html` `img tag` with `Html.ImageGetter`. But make sure your image is available in `resource drawable` folder

Here is a sample , The image will be loaded from the resource.

```
String htmlText = "Hai <img src=\"ic_launcher\"> Hello";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText, new Html.ImageGetter() {

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
   int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable",getPackageName());
   Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
   drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return drawable;
        }
    }, null));
```

Comment: Thanks, i've modified the code to work with url images

Comment: if htmlText contains multiple images , how to get those images , where images are present in SD card

Comment: @Libin how can we use the code when our image is from SD CARD/INTERNAL STOARGE..Please help me on it

Answer (score 2):

```
 String mIsi = (String) bundle.get("isi");
        isi.setText(Html.fromHtml(mIsi, new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(final String source) {
                Picasso.get()
                        .load(source).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        drawable = imageView.getDrawable();

                        drawable.setBounds(0, 0,
                                drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Log.v("test pic","err"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                return drawable;
            }
        }, null));
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some explanation to your code. At the very least, explain how it is different/better/more relevant than the accepted answer above.